# "Invalid API Key provided" error with Store and Stripe

Tags: expresso-store, stripe

I've checked the API several times and I'm sure the API code is correct, so I assume the problem is in [the code on this page](https://phorus.com/dev/index.php/store_example/checkout3). I installed the Store plugin and I'm trying to set up a Stripe payment gateway using the Store checkout3 template as a starting point.

In reviewing the docs, I see differences between the Store documentation regarding Stripe and the Stripe documentation itself. Since the Store docs suggestions checking the Stripe docs, I'm not sure which code to use when there is a discrepancy between the two sets of documentation. I don't know javascript yet so I have been testing parts of the Stripe code in place of the Store code, attempting to find a solution through trial and error. So far, nothing has worked. It's possible I just made an basic mistake. Help would be much appreciated.

I'm using the latest version of both EE and Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe has API keys for both Test Mode and Live Mode. Make sure the mode of the public API key used in your Store template matches the mode of the private key pasted into your Store settings for Stripe.

Comment: The Stripe settings in Store does not have Test or Live modes setting, but it does have a field where I had neglected to paste the private test API. Your answer caused me to check the settings an notice my oversight. Now it's finally working. Thanks!

Comment: A meta question, since I don't have permission to ask it in the appropriate forum: Should I alter Derek's answer to make it accurate and then check it as correct?

Comment: Just edited my answer to reflect that - glad I could help lead the way.

Comment: It would be nice if this were something where users could enter both sets of keys and not have to adjust in templates. Is this possible ?

Comment: Can you please tell where to get that api keys. I am not able to find that. Only what i have seen is publishable key and secret and client id, nothing else